# how value can be passed from one fragment to another fragment of viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-volley

FRAGMENT 1 :CONTAIN ONLY EDITTEXT
FRAGMENT 2 :CONTAIN ONLY EDITTEXT
FRAGMENT 3 :CONTAIN BUTTON AND EDITTEXT

fragment are in view pager
so,i want to pass value of fragment1 and fragment2 such that when i click on button
of third fragment all value from edittext(fragment1 and fragment2) get entered in database.i have already maintain database

Need help with simple example...Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use SharedPreferences.

Comment: Define an interface to your Fragment to your Activity

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: Have a look on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29731038/passing-data-beetwen-fragments-in-viewpager

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass values between Fragments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16036572/how-to-pass-values-between-fragments)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Basic Communication between two fragments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13700798/basic-communication-between-two-fragments)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener onPageSelected method.

Add a public method in your fragment like this :

```
private Object myObject;

public void addObject(Object sampleObject){
    myObject = sampleObject;
}
```

then in onPageSelected method you can try it with this:

```
@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    currentFragment = (Fragment) viewPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(mViewPager, position);

    if (currentFragment instanceof yourFragment ) {

        ((yourFragment ) currentFragment).addObject(objectToBePassed);
    }

}
```